# Cypher: group by cheapest price

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Im currently experimenting a bit with cypher. I have a simple setup of components beeing connected to a merchant by a realtionship "sells" having a property "price" 
(merchant-[:sells{price:10}]->component)
I made a cypher query which calculates the lowest price, if you buy products from the same merchant.

```
MATCH sup-[s:sells]->component 
WITH SUM(s.price) AS total, sup 
RETURN sup, total 
ORDER BY total ASC
```

Now while this is working, I have an issue finding the cheapest price(s), in case 2 or more suppliers are tied. Id like to get something like

```
_________________________
|  price  |   supplier  |
-------------------------
|   60    |    conrad   |
|         |    amazon   |
-------------------------
```

You can view my setup here:
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=wpz165

EDIT:
Ok, i found a way although it isnt pretty.

```
MATCH sup-[s:sells]->component 
WITH SUM(s.price) AS minprice, sup 
ORDER BY minprice 
LIMIT 1 
MATCH sup2-[s2:sells]->component2 
WITH SUM(s2.price) AS total2, sup2, minprice 
WHERE total2 = minprice 
RETURN minprice, sup2
```

How does this work? Well the first part finds the lowest price(by ordering and only returning the first row). The second part runs the whole query again, and filters out items which dont have the lowest price...so the whole query is run two times.
any better ideas???

Answer (score 0):

For my aesthetic this is less ugly though it does require three WITH clauses.

1. Sum price by supplier for all components
2. Find Minimum price
3. Return all suppliers with minimum price

   ```
   MATCH sup-[s:sells]->component 
   WITH sup, SUM(s.price) AS price_sum 
   MATCH sup, price_sum 
   WITH MIN(price_sum) AS price_min 
   MATCH sup2-[s2:sells]->component2 
   WITH sup2, SUM(s2.price) AS price_sum2, price_min 
   WHERE price_sum2 = price_min 
   RETURN sup2, price_sum2
   ```

Comment: Actually you dont need the second Match clause
`MATCH sup-[s:sells]->component 
WITH sup, SUM(s.price) AS price_sum 
WITH MIN(price_sum) AS price_min 
MATCH sup2-[s2:sells]->component2 
WITH sup2, SUM(s2.price) AS price_sum2, price_min 
WHERE price_sum2 = price_min 
RETURN sup2, price_sum2`

Comment: Did you try your cypher in the console?  When I run it I get no rows.  Probably because there is no price_min.                            MATCH sup-[s:sells]->component 
WITH sup, SUM(s.price) AS price_sum 
WITH MIN(price_sum) AS price_min 
RETURN price_min